Just the two of us
What answer is hidden below? As usual, explain your reasoning.




Just want to say, notice how the bottom left figure has thicker mid lines than the figure to it's right, that's actually intentional in case you wonder.

The answer is:

 BINARY


 

Here is the step by step process:

 Fold the four corners on the top two grids and you get 0 and 1.

Therefore

 Red is 0 and Blue is 1

Then on the bottom

 you ‘unfold’ the left grid (hence why the central lines are bold) and superimpose it on the right.

Using the top as a guide you get:

 From the top down: 10,1001,1110,1,10010,11001 convert these to into decimals and you get 2,9,14,1,18,25 and then covert those numbers into letters via the A1Z26 cipher and you get BINARY.


Ahh, silly mistake. Nonetheless, you got it ofc. Good job!

I guess you are going to leave it as it is?

Been busy, but I'll probably make an edit a bit later, if not early tommorow. I'll let you know.

I see np, btw keep up the good work, I have seen that a lot of your puzzles have been downvoted unjustly but they have been among the best I have seen here of late!

No prob, thanks. Edited now
